# Can Vortas get drunk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

Vortas make good diplomats because they are immune to many types of poison. Since alcohol is a poison, I wonder if a Vorta could drink even Scotty or Mr. Homn under the table.

Comment: Yes, they can get drunk. You have to liquefy them in a blender, pour them into a glass, and sell them to customers at Quark's Bar.

Comment: Unpleasantly like feeling of being drunk. What's unpleasant about being drunk? Ask a glass of water.

Comment: We know of a [rockstar Vorta](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Yelgrun), surely he could (and would) get drunk.

Answer (score 5):

**Probably Not**

The idea that "alcohol is a poison" is actually incorrect.  It can indeed poison you, or have toxic effects, when drunk in large enough doses.

Of course, the same is true of water.  No, I don't mean drowning.  I mean that if you drink enough water you can get [water intoxication](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/features/water-intoxication#1).

This is essentially what happens with alcohol.  Small, occasional doses (e.g.: a wine or beer at dinner) won't harm you, and can actually be beneficial.

But drink too much, and it can become toxic, even leading to alcohol poisoning.

As one doctor [points out](https://www.alcoholproblemsandsolutions.org/is-alcohol-a-poison/):

> A fundamental axiom of pharmaceutical science is simple. “The dosage makes the toxin.”

As to whether a Vorta can get drunk, it depends at what point their body starts to see the alcohol as toxic or poisonous.

On this we can only speculate: if being drunk, or even mildly buzzed, is enough for the Vorta's body to consider alcohol a toxin, then their immunity will kick in before that point, and they will never become drunk.

Unfortunately there isn't enough information to say for certain, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs. Everyone knew what I meant when I referred to alcohol as a poison.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - no I'm not.  I gave an analysis, with references, to try and determine at what point alcohol becomes poisonous to humans.  It technically is not poisonous from the very first drink.  The whole point is to show that while it might have some effect on a Vorta, its likely their immune system would kick in before it reached levels that would be considered toxic.  Presumably they can handle water in the same way.

Comment: Does it not do any damage at all, even negligible? Water does no damage unless you drink it like a fish.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - I looked up what research I could find, and it seems alcohol is like everything - in small enough dose, it's non-toxic.  I think the perceptions about it being toxic or poisonous come from the fact that you don't need _much_ of it before it starts effecting you.
Read the linked articles about water toxicity in my answer.  Just because it takes bucketloads doesn't mean it'd never toxic.  This is true for just about everything.

Comment: Enough of anything will kill you, but there's a reason why most parents don't want their child to drink alcohol, and like it when they drink water.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - not that I'm endorsing giving alcohol to a child, but a small amount won't do any harm.  Again, read the links.  It's up to you.